# Is there a way to play/pause the VSE from Blender's text editor with a hotkey?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

As many of you I believe, when I'm looking at some footage in the VSE, I often take notes in an external text editor but one could actually use blender's text editor as well. Would there be a way to play/pause the VSE from Blender's text editor with a hotkey? Without having to put you mouse on top of the VSE to use a hotkey, just using your keyboard while in the text editor.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the user preference > input ... you should be able to

1. Go search the VSE section and Text editor section.
2. Copy those shortcut that you want to invoke from VSE into the text editor section.
3. And you should be able to invoke VSE commands while your mouse is hovering upon text editor's screen estate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Created a play animation
screen.animation_play
in the text editor with a keyboard shortcut but coudn’t get it to play the VSE while in the text editor

Comment: It's working on my end. Look at my modified answer and try again. You want it on text (Global)

Comment: Many thanks. Won't work on my end with Alt A or Spacebar or Alt spacebar but works with F16.... Spacebar would have been great as it is commonly used in most editing softwares.

Comment: Probably you have to unset another already defined Global Hotkey first that prevents this new one from working?

Comment: @ Maxime it's definitely working on my machine, tested it. There must be some blockers on your end you need to remove. Make sure your text (Global) list do not have any command that is using the same Alt + A combination. It should work or else there is a bug going on at your end. Like what Samoth said.